# Does Rails support TCP/IP level operations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tcp

I'm working on a Rails project which requires integration with an outside component. Unfortunately, the only available communication channel is through TCP/IP. Can Rails operate on the TCP/IP layer? If not, is there any good Ruby libraries that I can use to easily integrate back to Rails?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a class in ruby standard library for this: [TCPSocket](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPSocket.html). It has everything you need.

Comment: how do i run this with Rails though? do i just write an infinite loop with TCPSocket in a task? How can I write this in a robust way?

Comment: Can you add more information about the component you're communicating with?  Such as - do you open and close the socket for each transaction, or do you need to keep it open? Rails can deal with either - the database adapters keep pools of open connections, for instance - but the details are what will make this tricky.